# FacetGrid shows no legend for histplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Let's say, I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "kind": "used",
    "val1": np.random.rand(100),
    "val2": np.random.rand(100),
})

df1.loc[0:50, "kind"] = "unused"

df_melt = pd.melt(df1, id_vars="kind", value_vars=["val1", "val2"])
```

The dataframe `df_melt` should now end up in FacetGrid where each plot is a histogram of one of the values (i.e. `val1` and `val2`). Within the plot, the `kind` column should be used as hue, so that we get two groups (the used and unused elements).

These groups should be shown in a legend somewhere in the plot.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df_melt, col="variable")
g.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, x="value", log_scale=True, hue="kind", legend=True)
```

which yields:

[image: plot of the data of df_melt]

However, as you can see, there is no legend being plotted. `g._legend_data` is also empty.

How do I get Seaborn to show a legend for my plot?

Comment: Did you try `sns.displot(data=df_melt, kind='hist', x="value", col="variable", ...)`? Usually, the specific grid functions (`sns.catplot`, `sns.relplot`, ...) work best.  Directly calling `sns.FacetGrid` needs to take quite some internals into account, which often aren't intuitive.

Comment: That worked flawlessly. Thanks a lot for the help!
I didn't know `sns.FacetGrid` was not meant to be called directly.

If you leave your comment as an answer, I can mark it as the accepted solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn's [FacetGrid documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) contains a warning in a colored box:

> When using seaborn functions that infer semantic mappings from a dataset, care must be taken to synchronize those mappings across facets (e.g., by defining the hue mapping with a palette dict or setting the data type of the variables to category). In most cases, it will be better to use a figure-level function (e.g. relplot() or catplot()) than to use FacetGrid directly.

For histograms you can use [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) to create a grid. It combines most parameters of `sns.FacetGrid` and `sns.histplot`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "kind": "used",
    "val1": np.random.rand(100),
    "val2": np.random.rand(100),
})

df1.loc[0:50, "kind"] = "unused"

df_melt = pd.melt(df1, id_vars="kind", value_vars=["val1", "val2"])

sns.displot(data=df_melt, kind='hist', x="value", col="variable", log_scale=True, hue="kind", legend=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: sns.displot instead of sns.FacetGrid]